How do you point a GoDaddy domain to Netlify website?
Any help would be appreciated, I could not get it working from the documentation.
I bought a domain from GoDaddy. I have a website hosted on Netlify but I need to point the domain. I have added the Netlify name servers to GoDaddy. What else do you have to do to get the domain working? I still get the Page not found - Looks like you’ve followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn’t exist on this site. error when I go to the website.
Is there something more you have to do then just point the name servers to Netlify to get the domain working?
